# itext keep paragraphs together

Tags: c#, itext

I have 2 paragraph objects that take up about 2/3 of the page. When I view it in the pdf the start of the 2nd paragraph starts on the 2nd page. Is there a way to start it on 1st page following the 1st paragraph?

```
    PdfPTable rs1 = new PdfPTable(1);            

    PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell();
    c.MinimumHeight = 36f;

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(
        "some text to align\n" +
        "..." +
        "some text to align\n" 
    );

    c.AddElement(p);

    rs1.AddCell(c);

    PdfPCell c2 = new PdfPCell();
    c.MinimumHeight = 36f;

    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(
        "some text to align\n" +
        "..." +
        "some text to align\n" +
        "some text to align\n"
    );
    p2.KeepTogether = false;
    c2.AddElement(p2);
    c2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

    rs1.AddCell(c2);

    return rs1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used PdfPTable.SplitLate = false

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't with your paragraphs but with your table. iTextSharp tries to not break content across table cells and your current layout appears to do that. Do you need to have a table? Regular paragraphs will just break when a line goes off the viewable area. If you need tables then you'll have to adjust the table's width if you can (`rs1.WidthPercentage = 100;`) and possibly any padding that you've set up.